# Gulp task to bundle bower_components?

Tags: bower, gulp

I'd appreciate it so much if someone could please tell me a good way to handle bundling bower components.  I feel like I've tried everything... Although, I can't seem to find any gulp tasks that handle this already.  Could it really not exist?

Let's say it doesn't exist.  Worst case scenario is I have to specify the paths of each "dist" file from bower_components folder.  (It is annoying that each component seems to have its own "dist" folder... nothing is standardized.)

So even if I do that, I've noticed some components like 'active-support' seem to have `require('lodash')` and such in them.  I think that if I just simply copy that file, it will break because the requires won't resolve.

What am I missing?  How do I simply take all bower_components and bundle into a "common.js"... is there a way or is it a clusterfluck?

Comment: why not use gulp-usemin, and let it read sections of index.html to know which files to concat

Comment: I have the same sort of question...

Answer (score 12):

### Update

As pointed out by Alerty, the new Gulp policy seems to be: use bower directly and glob patterns (and hope that the packages maintainers have a proper "ignore" properties).

---

### Previously

You can use [main-bower-files](https://github.com/ck86/main-bower-files) or [gulp-bower-src](https://github.com/bclozel/gulp-bower-src) to get files from your bower components. They can also use "ignore" or "main" overrides in your own bower file.

Comment: -1 Blacklisted by gulp, use bower module directly and globs... https://github.com/gulpjs/plugins/blob/master/src/blackList.json

Comment: updated my answer with latest gulp recommendations; left the old one for historical purposes and because the blacklist is about best practices.

Comment: I am new to bower and I don't get it. what do you mean by use bower directly and glob patterns? what are those ignore properties?

Comment: each bower.json file is written in a specific format (see https://github.com/bower/bower.json-spec); when getting a bower dependency, you're not getting the files listed in the "ignore" property. At some point, the community discussed an optional  "override" option (https://github.com/bower/bower.json-spec/pull/27) to override your dependencies.

And by glob patterns, I mean doing something like `gulp.src("./lib/**).pipe(...).pipe(gulp.dest("../dist/"));` if your bower libs are in `"lib"`

Comment: @Brian Clozel Is it possible to copy all the `.js` file in to one specific folder ?

Comment: This really could use better documentation, when I hear "user bower module directly" i think of the gulp-bower module, which is blacklisted. I actually have no idea how to do this now.

Comment: I am new to bower and I need to work on the published project. Not sure what I need to do to get it to work?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I managed it (but see gulpfile.js for project structure, it's not a single gigantic gulpfile) :

https://github.com/notbrain/viceroy/blob/master/gulp/tasks/bower.js

Would be a bit more modular to simply concat all bower deps and then do the uglify() and minifyCSS() tasks separately on dist/ source locations, based on dev/prod env targets, but will have to wait for future updates.

Answer (score 0):

Use [main-bower-files](https://www.npmjs.com/package/main-bower-files):

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var mainBowerFiles = require('main-bower-files');

gulp.task('TASKNAME', function() {
    return gulp.src(mainBowerFiles())
        .pipe(/* what you want to do with the files */)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have folders like:

```
-app
-bower
-node_modules
Gulpfile.js
package.json
```

the solution are:

```
gulp.task("connect", function () {
  connect.server({
    root: ["app"],
    livereload: true,
    port: 8034,
    middleware: function (connect) {
      return [connect().use("/bower", connect.static("bower"))];
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If your project use AMD specification.

You can use [gulp-edp](https://github.com/junmer/gulp-edp) bundle the modules.

set module info at **module.conf**

```
{
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {},
    "packages": [
        {
            "name": "etpl",
            "location": "../bower_components/etpl/3.0.1/src",
            "main": "main"
        },
        {
            "name": "jquery",
            "location": "../bower_components/jquery/1.9.1/src",
            "main": "jquery.min"
        }
    ],
    "combine": {
        "app": true
    }
}
```

***gulpfile.js***

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var edp = require('gulp-edp');

gulp.src(
    [
        'src/**/*.js'
        'bower_components/**/*.js',
        '!bower_components/**/{demo,demo/**}',
        '!bower_components/**/{test,test/**}'
    ]
)
.pipe(edp({
    getProcessors: function () {
        var moduleProcessor = new this.ModuleCompiler();
        return [moduleProcessor];
    }
}))
.pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
```

See [EDP wiki](https://github.com/ecomfe/edp/wiki/Build-Processors#modulecompiler) for more features.